# Animate a Stick Figure with Cocos2d, images vs. drawing?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone

I saw this question on a Cocos2d forum, and I would really like to see the answer, I'm assuming its more likely to get answered here:

I was wondering what would be the best method to go about animating a stick figure running, walking, etc.
I need to have a wide and flexible range of motion, so prefer to actually animate multiple lines rather than create premade images and flip through them.
Would I use rotation or use trigonometry to figure coordinates from the angle of the moving extremities?
Any advice, direction or code snippets would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You could set your own anchor points for each sprite to animate with the rotation- that way you could rotate an arm from the end of the arm just by using rotate instead of doing a lot of complicated math. Setting the anchor point also allows you to translate the sprite along that point instead of its center. [Anchorpoint tutorial](http://www.qcmat.com/understanding-anchorpoint-in-cocos2d/).

However, I think that it might be easier just to create a lot of images of the stick figure doing all of the actions. I think that [n game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N_%28video_game%29) does this and their character has a lot of animations.